# Script to create Samba users from txt file

Tags: linux, scripting, redhat, samba

I have a simple text file with one username/password combo per line:

```
user1 p@55w0rD1
user2 p@55w0rD2
```

I used this simple script to import my user list on the Linux side:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read u1 p1
do
   echo Username: $u1 Password: $p1 created
   adduser $u1
   echo $p1 | passwd --stdin "$u1"
echo Username: $u1 Password: $p1 created
done < userlist.txt
```

Can this script be modified so that I can add this same user list to Samba? The thing I'm stumbling on is smbpasswd -a prompts for a password immediately and I'm not sure how to handle that in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$@" in 
    add  )  for user in  `cat  user.txt`
    do
        smbpasswd  -a $user
        echo samba_password | passwd  --stdin  $user
    done;; 
    * )  echo"Please enter an argument....";;
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but when I run it, I get the following error: `line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file`